# WinForms Event Parent scroll

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two `FlowLayoutPanels` on a form: `PanelA` and `PanelB`. Each will be populated at run-time with multiple controls, such that the panel will scroll (i.e `AutoScroll` is true).

Here's the issue: The controls that the panels are populated with each contain a `ComboBox`. Thus, `MouseWheel` events are consumed by the combo box instead of by the panel. I want `MouseWheel` events to be consumed by the panel.

If there's no scrollable control on the child controls, then the `MouseWheel` event skips the child control (which doesn't handle it) and hits the panel, which does handle it. How can I set my child control's combo box to ignore the `MouseWheel` event? Can I tell it to re-raise the event?

I tried just applying Focus to the Parent whenever one of the child controls ticks the 'MouseEnter' event; this fixed the scrolling issues, but also left the child controls completely un-editable.

Something else I've found from digging around involves fiddling with the Windows API directly, but I find it hard to believe that something like that is required for this.

Comment: To be clear, when you click on the panel and scroll, the combobox still eats the events, correct?

Comment: @Kreep: Correct-ish. The functionality appears to be as follows:

If child control is clicked, focus defaults to first focus-able control by tab-index (the combo box, which consumes scroll wheel events). If another focus-able control in the child control is selected which does not consume scroll wheel events, the panel scrolls as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the following code and it seems like a solution to your issue. Basically you need to focus the 'FlowLayoutPanel' when you click on it, or your mouse enters it:

```
private void newCheckListQuestionPanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   newCheckListQuestionPanel.Focus(); //allows the mouse wheel to work after the panel is clicked
}
private void newCheckListQuestionPanel_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   newCheckListQuestionPanel.Focus(); //allows the mouse wheel to work after the panel has had the mouse move over it
}
```

- [Source](http://thewayofcoding.com/2008/02/c-net-programming-tip-flowlayoutpanel-mouse-scroll-wheel-not-working/)

Comment: Perfect, that solved my issue. As per the blog post, I left out the Click event and it still worked.

Unlike applying Focus to the parent on the MouseEnter event (as I tried above), this solution (MouseEnter on the panel) leaves the child controls manipulable.

Thanks!